# Frameworks for distributed Go (like Erlang OTP)?

Tags: go, distributed, distributed-computing

Seems like Go is gaining traction and there are lots of interesting projects using it.

But, I frequently heard an opinion that Go primary focus is single machine, unlike Erlang OTP it doesn't have good support for building distributed systems.

So, what frameworks and approaches available for Go to build **reliable** distributed systems?

Important thing - such frameworks should be battle tested and **used in production** with heavy load, not just popular on GitHub.

Comment: People who downvoted this, could you give the reason.

Comment: The question is dedicated to Go but erlang tag is used. This is the wraith of bothered erlangers.

Comment: Or just the idea that something like OTP can be ported to another language like some secondary library, like, as an afterthought. GoCircuit doesn't really seem to compare.

Comment: I removed the Erlang tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last [GopherCon 2014](http://www.gophercon.com/) had several of those frameworks for distributed systems:

- [The Go Circuit: Towards Elastic Computation with No Failures](http://www.gophercon.com/schedule/#petar_maymounkov): [gocircuit/circuit](https://github.com/gocircuit/circuit)

> Somewhat unlike Erlang, where the distributed operating system OTP is below the language, we assert that the distributed OS should be built above and using the language.

- [Writing a High Performance Database in Go](http://www.gophercon.com/schedule/#ben_johnson): [`skydb/sky`](https://github.com/skydb/sky) and [skydb.io](http://skydb.io/), with its last release including distributed computing, so you can run Sky across multiple nodes and scale linearly.
- [Spray Some NSQ On It](http://www.gophercon.com/schedule/#matt_reiferson): [bitly/nsq](https://github.com/bitly/nsq) and [nsq.io](http://nsq.io/)

> NSQ is a realtime distributed messaging platform, built entirely in Go, that promotes distributed and decentralized topologies without single points of failure, enabling fault tolerance and high availability coupled with a reliable message delivery guarantee.

The first and third are used in production.